# Delete records of a certain date in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with a column named timestamp

```
timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
```

which stores records in the table like this:

```
2010-12-06 18:41:37
```

How can I delete records of a certain date?
I'm using:

```
DELETE FROM sessions WHERE timestamp = '2010-12-06';
```

but this is not working. am i missing something here?

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8):

```
DELETE FROM sessions WHERE timestamp = '2010-12-06'
```

is basically selecting and deleting any records timestamped as '2010-12-06 00:00:00'

You would be better off defining a range:

```
DELETE FROM sessions WHERE timestamp >= '2010-12-06' AND timestamp < '2010-12-07'
```

will delete any sessions that fell in that range.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Date function to extract and compare just the date:

```
DELETE FROM sessions WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2010-12-06'
```